# C++ header file inclusion error

Tags: c++

I have a header "myHeaderFile.h" file looks as below which is used by both release exe and unit test exe.

```
#ifndef MYHEADERFILE_H
#define MYHEADERFILE_H

namespace myname1
{
namespace myname2
{
    class A
    { 
           ...
    };
#ifdef MYTESTCLASS
    class TestABase
    {
        ...
    }
#endif
}
}
#endif
```

Now we have for unittest file myUnitTest.h file file as below

```
#ifndef MYUNITEST_H
#define MYUNITTEST_H

#ifndef MYTESTCLASS
#define MYTESTCLASS  1
#endif 
#include "myHeaderFile.h"
class TestClass : public myname1::myname2::TestABase
{
  ...
};
#endif
```

now in myUnitTest.cpp i have following

```
#include "myUnitTest.h"

// Definition stuff.
```

When i compile i am getting error as error C2039: TestABase: is not a member of myname1::myname2'
myUnitTest.h(31): error C2504: TestABase: base class undefined

what is causing above error? Please help me in resolving above error. Note: myHeaderFile.h comes from library so i cannot change this header file.

Thanks!

Comment: the code snippet was modified as indicated by Juraj Blaho and now it compiles fine. You should not modify code snippets and add the solution to them, but instead you should close the question by aproving the answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `myHeaderFile.h` in `myUnitTest.h`. Do that after the block:

```
#ifndef MYTESTCLASS
#define MYTESTCLASS  1
#endif
```

**Edit**

As this did not help then there may be a problem with the `MYTESTCLASS` definition. Do you include `myHeaderFile.h` anywhere else? Maybe you can try to define the `MYTESTCLASS` in compiler options instead of in the `myUnitTest.h` header file. Maybe you can just remove the `#ifdef MYTESTCLASS` check to see if that is the problem.